# Server.MapPath does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Inside my MVC4 project I have the namespace

> prj.MVC4.Controllers

where I'm using `Server.MapPath(..)` without problem and on

> prj.MVC4.Models

`Server.MapPath(...)` does not exist on current context.

I'm aware that `Server.MapPath` resides in `System.Web` and both namespace and assembly are added into class with using `System.Web` and `System.Web.dll` is added to the prj.

on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. I'm getting  `Microsoft.SqlServer` as suggested namespace to add.

How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server.MapPath does not exist in the Current Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122119/server-mappath-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Server is a property of the controller, to access it elsewhere while running a web application you can use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server
```

Comment: it says `current` is a property but it used like a type.

Comment: How do I access that within my Web Handler file?

Answer (score 7):

`Server` property is accessible from within controller. You can also find it in `HttpContext.Current` provided that your app is executed inside asp.net environment.

Comment: I had to earn a badge for this one, my bad

Comment: @neolace I don't get it, what do you mean by  "I had to earn a badge for this one, my bad"?

Comment: I don't either, edit you q so I can upvote. My profile stated that my next goal would be to downvote an answer, your answer happened to be the chosen 1. After down voting your q, nothing changed on my side, I made a mistake, apologies for that.

Comment: @neolace randomly downvoting correct answers is not the way to go.

Comment: ok, let's start with your answer, read your answer again, maybe then you'll understand.