# Why I can't use Server.MapPath() in my class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following problem when I try to call the **Server.MapPath();** inside a class.

It give to me the following error message:

> Error 3   The name 'Server' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\iTextDocumentBase.cs  122 13  PdfReport

So I think that maybe I have to add the namespace related to the Server object but looking on the official documentation I can't found no related namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Why? What can I do to solve?

Tnx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195663/server-mappath-does-not-exist-in-currect-context

Answer (score 4):

do like this in class:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Relative path");
```

Answer (score 1):

Server is object in the `Page` class so you need to inherit the `Page` class or get through `Page` class object. You can use  [System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.server%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in you do not need to use `Page` class.