# Server.MapPath does not exist in the Current Context

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# Model Class where I am trying to access a `.cshtml` page which is supposed to be an email format template. I'm using the following code:

```
string body = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailConfTemplate.cshtml")))
{
     body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But i am getting the following error message:

> The name Server does not exist in the current context

Is there any error in the code or the `Server` class can't be accessed in POCO class. Please help.

Comment: Hi Lara, 
On the MVC approach, you shouldn't do that code in the Model Class, but in the Controller.

Comment: @PauloCorreia But its not a `MVC` project..

Comment: Use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath() `

Comment: @Lara, what kind of project is it?

Comment: However, you're using a model class and accessing a `.cshtml` view, so why is it not MVC?  More to the point, why are you reading in the view into the model? Seems very odd.  It's generally better to explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than a snippet of code and 'why doesn't this work?'.  From your approach, you're likely to run in a whole load of other problems

Comment: @nicodemus13 I am using ServiceStack as framework for my application.My .cshtml page is just a basic Email template that i want to send by email so i am trying to read that in model

Comment: @PauloCorreia I am using ServiceStack framework for this

Comment: @Lara: Ok, However, I was referring to MVC in general, not ASP.NET MVC. It's usually better if models are dumb DTOs, also, it's probably better to inject the path to the template from a 'controller', into which the path is also injected (set it at the top of the call-chain), otherwise you're creating unnecessary dependencies, making refactoring/ testing and general coding far more difficult

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To execute it inside a .Net pipeline, you can find it as an instance present in `HttpContext`

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()
```

Comment: Now i am getting `HttpContext` does not exist in the current Context

Comment: It might be the case you have not imported `System.Web` so try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()`

Comment: NOw i am getting `The type or namespace name HttpContext does not exist in the namespace System.web (r u missing a assembly refrence`

Comment: I added and now error is resolved . Let me test it on Server if Working I will Mark this as Answer.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Server.MapPath("~/EmailConfTemplate.cshtml")
```

Try using

```
string fullPath = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}\\EmailConfTemplate.cshtml", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\"))).ToString();
```