# Error: The name server does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, server, windows

I am using windows application to send mail with the attachment. But at this line of code I get error as

> The name 'server' does not exist in current context

```
var directory = Server.MapPath("Attachment/");
```

I tried from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122119/server-mappath-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) but it was not working for me

Comment: Your error states you have a variable called `server`, not `Server` (notice the case). So I doubt the error is at that line (or you did not copy the error properly)

Comment: Server.MapPath is typically used with ASP.net, why would you want to use it in a windows app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a Server object in a windows application, the Server object is for web applications only.

You can simply specify the full local path to the directory and use this, unlike having to map it based on a virtual directory as in a web application.

If the path to your files/directory are contained in the same folder as your application, you can use `Application.StartupPath` property and combine this with your own values to get a full path.

```
var directory =  Application.StartupPath + "\\Attachment\\";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I Left from office, will try tomorrow and let u know

Comment: Tried but getting error as `Could not find file 'D:\CRM_CustHold\CustomerFollowUp\CustomerFollowUp\bin\Debug\AttachmentEmployee_Details.xls'.`

Comment: Should that not be 'D:\CRM_CustHold\CustomerFollowUp\CustomerFollowUp\bin\Debug\Attachment\Employee_‌​Details.xls'?

Comment: yeah, my syntax mistake.. Also the attachment is going but the file is not getting saved in the `attachment` folder

Comment: That would need to be a separate question I would say. ;)

Comment: Ask away and I will see whether I know of an answer